# Split objects in array, based on the property

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I want to duplicate entire objects inside an array, based on the properties inside the object. I need to duplicate the objects, based on the split emails, in nominations.

For example

```
array = [
{
  id:1,
  name: ravi,
  nominations: xyz@gmail.com, abc@gmail.com
},
{
   id:2
   name: ramu,
   nominations: 123@gmail.com, 456@gmail.com
}
]
```

Need Output like

```
Output_array = [
{
  id:1,
  name: ravi,
  nominations: xyz@gmail.com
},
{
  id:1,
  name: ravi,
  nominations: abc@gmail.com
},
{
   id:2
   name: ramu,
   nominations: 123@gmail.com
},
{
   id:2
   name: ramu,
   nominations: 456@gmail.com
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to `flatMap` over the items, then `map` over the nominations.

```js
const data = [{
  id:1,
  name: "ravi",
  nominations: "xyz@gmail.com, abc@gmail.com"
},
{
   id:2,
   name: "ramu",
   nominations: "123@gmail.com, 456@gmail.com"
}];

const result = data.flatMap(item => {
  return item.nominations.split(", ").map(email => ({
    id: item.id,
    name: item.name,
    nomination: email
  }))
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty straightforward way using loops:

```js
let data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ravi",
    "nominations": "xyz@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ramu",
    "nominations": "123@gmail.com,456@gmail.com"
  }
];

let newData = []
for (let element of data) {
  let emailIds = element.nominations.split(",");
  if (emailIds.length > 1) {
    for (let emailId of emailIds)
      newData.push({ id: element.id, name: element.name, nominations: emailId })
  }
}

console.log(newData)
```

**Explanation**: Starting with traversing the entire objects, in each object you split the `nominations` string and split it with "," to check if there is more than one email. If it does exist, you run a loop to individually add them.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with an arguably long one-liner. `Object.assign` function can be employed to duplicate input object while changing property/properties of interest.

```js
let input = [{
    id: 1,
    name: `ravi`,
    nominations: `xyz@gmail.com, abc@gmail.com`
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: `ramu`,
    nominations: `123@gmail.com, 456@gmail.com`
}];

let output = input.flatMap(i => i.nominations.split(",").map(n => Object.assign({}, i, { nominations: n.trim() })));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data_array = [
                      {
                        id:'1',
                        name: 'ravi',
                        nominations: 'xyz@gmail.com, abc@gmail.com',
                      },
                      {
                         id:'2',
                         name: 'ramu',
                         nominations: '123@gmail.com, 456@gmail.com',
                      },
                    ];
    
    
    var output_array = data_array.flatMap(key => {
      return key.nominations.split(",").map(split_email => ({
        id: key.id,
        name: key.name,
        nomination: $.trim(split_email)
      }))
    });
    
    console.log(output_array);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```